# Colouring an unordered list?

Tags: html, css

I am to create a navigation menu using an unordered list in html. I am now trying to style the list to appear on one line, and to have a background colour, but I cannot get the colour to work. I have tried the `background:` and `background-color:` to add a background colour to my unordered list, but it doesn't see to appear in my result.

```css
/* styling nav list */

ul#navlist {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  list-style: none;
}

#navlist li {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}

li.nav {
  background-color: hsla(232°, 38%, 15%, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navlist">
    <!-- Unordered list = navigation menu -->
    <ul id="navlist">
      <li class="nav"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="fun_facts.html">Fun Facts</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="news.html">News</a></li>
      <li class="nav"><a href="merch.html">Merchandise</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

As a last resort, I tried to apply a background colour to each list item which didn't work.
Any ideas on how to fix would be appreciated.

Comment: `hsla`'s first argument can be unitless for degrees, or it should use `deg`, not the degree symbol.

Comment: Remove the little degree sign in the `hsla(...)`, and everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The hsla function's first paramater should not have the degrees symbol (°) on it.
It should just be `background-color: hsla(232, 38%, 15%, 0.2);`

You can find examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_hsla.asp